# Add hardcoded information to a taken photo (Android)

Tags: android, image

My question: is it possible to add *hardcoded* information (for example the current date, current speed, ...) to a taken photo? With *hardcoded* I mean not stored in the meta data, but directly on a picture.

---

Background: my intentian was to create a "CarCam" that records a video with addition information like the current speed.

The easy part - showing these data on the mobile phone screen - is already done (`SurfaceView` which is overlayed by a `TextView`). But the second part - saving a picture or video with these information - is really unclear to me. Is this possible? I searched for around the past 3 hours but i could not found any hint that this is possible anyway...

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit: one way could be to manipulate the `byte[]` given by `PictureCallback` method `onPictureTaken`, but this seems really badly to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Canvas` from your `Bitmap` like 
`Canvas c = new Canvas(/*your*/bitmap);` than using that canvas you can draw some basic shapes and text on to the bitmap. After that save the bitmap as usual.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: I just got a question: this is not really applicable for videos... is there also a solution?

Comment: @copakawusau Not that I realy know of. You can check opencv. It might be a solution. http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

Comment: @copakawusau by the way why it is not applicable? How do you take images and make video from them? Can you show some code?